# Finding the element with the lowest difference in an ArrayList when compared to a constant

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to have this code determine which element has the closest value to a constant.

In this code the variable `boxes = 5`, any element that has `boxCapacity >= boxes` is added to an ArrayList. From that list, the one with the closest `boxCapacity` to `boxes` should be used. I am able to select those greater than `boxes`, but unable to pick that with the closest `boxCapacity`.

```
public void deliver(double miles, int boxes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
        if (cars.get(i).getBoxCapacity() >= boxes){
            deliveryCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
            deliveryCars.add(cars.get(i));
            smallest = deliveryCars.get(0).getBoxCapacity();
            for(j = 0; j < deliveryCars.size(); j++){
               if (deliveryCars.get(j).getBoxCapacity() < smallest) {
                  smallest = deliveryCars.get(j).getBoxCapacity();
                  k++;
               }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Delivering with " + deliveryCars.get(k).getPlate());
}
```

I tried to make a new list, but it has not been working out.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code to something that looks like that

```
public void deliver(double miles, int boxes){
        // check if there are cars availible
        if (!cars.isEmpty()) {
            // assume that first car in a list is best for delivery
            int smallest = cars.get(0).getBoxCapacity();
            Car deliveryCar = cars.get(0);
            // iterating over all cars in a list
            // but still compares to the first car in a list 
            for (Car car : cars) {
                if (car.getBoxCapacity() >= boxes
                        && car.getBoxCapacity() < smallest) {
                    deliveryCar = car;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Delivering with " + deliveryCar.getPlate());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 streams...

```
Car deliveryVehicle = cars
    .stream()
    .filter(c -> c.getBoxCapacity() > boxes)
    .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getBoxCapacity))
    .orElse(null);
```

Assuming your `cars` was an iterable/streamable collection, this creates a stream, filters it to extract all instances where the capacity is greater than `boxes`, finds the element with the smallest capacity, and returns it, or `null` if there were no cars with more than `boxes` capacity.

You can then do whatever you want with the returned `Car` object, like call `getPlate()`. Remember to check for null for the case where no acceptable car was found.

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you're saying is that you have of list of values say `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and then you are given another number say `4`, and what you want to do is to select the number from the list that is the smallest of all the numbers greater than `4`, so in this case you'd want to choose `5`, right?

Well, there are a ton of ways to do that. But the fastest way to do it is to go through the list one time and keep track of the smallest number greater than your 'targetNumber':

```
...
public Integer getNextBiggest(List<Integer> numbers, int targetNumber) 
{
  // Set the default 'nextInt' to the largest possible value.
  int nextInt = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    // If the current number is greater than our targetNumber.
    if (sortedList.get(i) > targetNumber) {
      // Set the nextInt variable to the MINIMUM of current number
      // and the current nextInt value.
      nextInt = Math.min(nextInt, sortedList.get(i));
    }          
  }

  return nextInt;
}
...
```

So that would work, but your list is a bit more complicated since you're using Objects and not integers, that said, it's a simple conversion:

First some assumptions:

1. `cars` is a List.
2. `Car` object has a `getBoxCapacity()` method that returns an `int`.
3. `Car` object has a `getPlate()` method that returns a `String`.

Ok so it might look like this:

```
...
public Car getBestFitCar(List<Car> cars, int targetBoxCapacity) 
{
  // Default best fit is null. No best first yet.
  Car bestFit = null;

  for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {

    Car current = cars.get(i);

    // If the current Car box capacity is greater than our target box capacity.
    if (current.getBoxCapacity() > targetBoxCapacity) {
      // Set the bestFit variable to the Car that has the MINIMUM 
      // 'box capacity' between the current Car and the bestFit Car.
      if (bestFit == null || bestFit.getBoxCapacity() > current.getBoxCapacity()) {
        bestFit = current;
      }
    }          
  }


  return bestFit;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
  // add some cars here...
  int targetBoxCapacity = 5;

  Car bestFit = getBestFitCar(cars, targetBoxCapacity);

  if (bestFit != null) {
    System.out.println("Best fit car is: " + bestFit.getPlate());
  } else {
    System.out.println("No car can fit " + targetBoxCapacity + " boxes.");
  }
}
```

**Update:** 
I've seen some nice responses using streams, but I'd to add some caution. Streams make writing the code faster/more readable but would end up being less efficient in time/space than a solution with simple loops. This solution only uses O(1) extra space, and O(n) time in the worst case.

I'd figure the stream answers would use O(n) extra space, and O(n * n log n) time in the worst case.

So, if you have a tiny list I'd say go with the simple really cool streams solutions, but you have a list of a lot of elements that you'll be better off with a more traditional approach.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a new list. The task you've outlined is a sequential search through an unordered list, and unless I misunderstand your goal, you only need a single `for` loop -- that is, you only need to iterate through the list one time. Since you are looking for a single item and you don't need to look at more than one item at a time to see if it's the best one so far, you only need one variable to keep track of its location in the list.

Here's a working sample. Notice the variable names describe the purpose (e.g. "mimimumBoxCapacity" instead of the ambiguous "boxes"). This helps me better understand what my code is doing.

```
// print the plate number of the car with the smallest boxCapacity
// greater than a specified minimum
public void deliver(List<Car> cars, double miles, int minimumBoxCapacity)
{
    if ((cars != null) && (cars.size() > 0))
    {
        int indexOfBestMatch = -1; // negative index means no match yet
        for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++)
        {
            if (cars.get(i).getBoxCapacity() > minimumBoxCapacity)
            {
                if (indexOfBestMatch < 0)
                {
                    // this is the only match seen so far; remember it
                    indexOfBestMatch = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    // found a better match; replace the old best match
                    if (cars.get(i).getBoxCapacity() < cars.get(indexOfBestMatch).getBoxCapacity())
                    {
                        indexOfBestMatch = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (indexOfBestMatch >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Delivering with " + cars.get(indexOfBestMatch).getPlate());
        }
    }
}
```

This code illustrates how your algorithm would need to change to do what you want. DataDino's answer using a Car variable to keep track of the best fit is even clearer, especially where the method returns a Car result and lets the calling logic decide what to do with that result.

(Your original code didn't compile, because variables like "smallest" and "deliveryCars" weren't defined before they were used. It would be helpful in the future if you post code that compiles, even if it doesn't yet do what you want it to do.)

Answer (score 0):

This answer builds from the clarifications that @DataDino provided, namely that the goal is to find the car with the lowest boxCapacity that is greater than the targetCapacity.

Given the list of cars, you can filter out any car with a boxCapacity smaller than the target, and then select the minimum boxCapacity from what is left.

```
List<Car> cars = List.of(new Car(8), new Car(3), new Car(5), new Car(6));
int suggestedCapacity = 4;

Optional<Car> bestFit = cars.stream()
                   .filter(car -> car.getBoxCapacity() >= suggestedCapacity)
                   .min(Comparator.comparing(Car::getBoxCapacity));

if (bestFit.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println("found car with capacity " + bestFit.get().getBoxCapacity());
} else {
    System.out.println("No suitable car found");
}
```

The Streams api takes care of the list manipulation and keeping track of the internal state of the minimum for you.